# Javascript Geofire + Firebase react app - inconsitencies in instantiations/declarations in class based logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, geofire

Ok so I'm following example on setting up Geofire with Firebase as described in this example: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/examples/html5Geolocation/js/html5Geolocation.js

If I do the following in a normal JS code file the geoFire variable is set fine:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import GeoFire from 'geofire';

const config = {
    // config stuff here
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let geoLocationRef = firebase.database().ref('users-geolocation').push();
let geoFire = new GeoFire(geoLocationRef);
console.log('GEOFIRE :::::: ', geoFire);
// output: GEOFIRE ::::::  GeoFire {ref: ƒ, set: ƒ, get: ƒ, remove: ƒ, query: ƒ}
```

HOWEVER, if I try to do something similar in a GeoFireUtil.js class so that I can more easily include the GeoFire functionality where ever I want I am getting 'geoFire is undefined':

```
import firebase from './firebase-connection';
import GeoFire from 'geofire';

// geofire connection ##################

//let geoLocationRef = firebase.database().ref('users-geolocation').push();
// Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
//let geoFire = new GeoFire(geoLocationRef.child('geofire'));

class GeoFireUtil {

    constructor(userId, username) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.geoLocationRef = firebase.database().ref('users-geolocation').push();
        this.geoFire = new GeoFire(this.geoLocationRef);
        console.log('CLASS GEOFIRE ::::: ', this.geofire);
// output: CLASS GEOFIRE :::::  undefined
    }

....

}
```

I have yet to master JS and some concepts still escape me...can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I had the wrong variable name in the class.